# TSQL pivot per x rows having no groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell

After having searched quite a while I'm beginning to think that the following isn't possible.
Can anyone disprove me in a way that doesn't include those fun RBAR while loops?

I have several thousands of rows of data in the form of

```
ItemName  ItemNumber
itemA     1
itemB     2
itemC     3
itemD     4
itemE     1
itemF     2
itemA     3
itemZ     4
itemX     1
itemQ     2
itemR     3
itemS     4
```

My end result is wanting to get this into the following format

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
ItemA    ItemB    ItemC    ItemD
ItemE    ItemF    ItemA    ItemZ
ItemX    ItemQ    ItemR    ItemS
```

I've tried pivotting, but this only returns the top row if I pivot max(ItemNumber).
I've tried cross tabs but they don't seem to do what I need.
The column names can be blank in the final output. However, they are defined in the first set of items if that is of any use in your solution.

Is it possible to "pivot" this kind of data, and if so, what would be the best way?
I'm working with SQL Server 2014 and would love to keep the solution confined to TSQL.
However, if not possible in TSQL, you can consider using PowerShell as well.

Answer (score 2):

you could calculate a row_number but i'm not sure which column to use:

```
select * 
from ( select ItemName, ItemNumber
            , row_number() over (partition by ItemNumber order by  ItemName) rn
       from item 
      ) ps
pivot ( 
  MIN(ItemName)
  FOR ItemNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) pt
```

result:

```
╔════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║     rn ║   1   ║   2   ║   3   ║   4   ║
╠════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║ itemA ║ itemB ║ itemA ║ itemD ║
║      2 ║ itemE ║ itemF ║ itemC ║ itemS ║
║      3 ║ itemX ║ itemQ ║ itemR ║ itemZ ║
╚════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: I was about to post somewhat similar solution :) anyway +1

Comment: Try `ORDER BY ItemNumber` as well, so that it's more arbitrary, to give a better chance of matching the desired output. For the OP: What's going on here is that a column is being created in the result set to allow a traditional pivot operation to work. You don't need to return it - it's only there so that the pivot operation knows how to separate the rows. If you run the inner query, you'll see how those numbers are allocated. By using row_number and partition by the ColumnNumber column, you know that you won't be trying to squeeze two values into the same pivot cell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Sadly enough this isn't the solution, I'm getting the same result as I previously saw.

While the rows get pivoted into columns, the data in them isn't in the correct order anymore.
As you'd expect with the order by ItemName or ItemNumber the result scrambles all the data so that the order by gets respected.

When making each ItemName unique in my example, this is more easily apparent.

Instead i need the items from from the first series of ItemNumbers to be on row 1, 2nd series of ItemNumbers needs to be on row 2 etc...


Is this possible?

Comment: @JanMulkens do you have any other column or only this 2?